# My cookie code is not working

Tags: cookies

I'm trying to use cookies, but my most basic code below doesn't work. The page stays blank and is not saying anything. My cookies are enabled, and I'm using UTF-8 encoding.

I tried codes from various websites. They are working fine until I make even a little change (e.g. use another name for the cookie or put another text in the cookie). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $username = "Test";
    setcookie("username", $username, time()+365*24*60*60, '/', "localhost");
    echo $_COOKIE["username"];
?>

<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Alex Porter";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The superglobal `$_COOKIE` is not updated by the `set_cookie()` function.  If you want your cookie to be immediately available you need to also manually set the value of `$_COOKIE[$name]`.  Something like this

```
<?php 
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Alex Porter";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
?>
```

Comment: Oh i think i explained my problem wrong, the page stays empty even after a few reloads. I think the cookies dont get set, i also can't find them under my settings/cookies